# How do I do collision-detection in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I have been writing this code recently and I wanted collision-detection but I  have never done it before and I need help. this code is written with python and pygame so it should be simple but I'm not sure whether I should have the whole world as a transparent image

```
import pygame, os, itertools
from pygame.locals import *

w = 640
h = 480
pink = (0,179,179)
player_x = 39
player_y = 320

def setup_background():
    screen.fill((pink))
    screen.blit(playerImg, (player_x,player_y))
    screen.blit(brick_tile, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((w, h))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
playerImg = pygame.image.load('img/player.png').convert_alpha()
brick_tile = pygame.image.load('img/map.png').convert_alpha()

class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/player.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

class World(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    allsprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
    def __init__(self):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.image.load('img/map.png')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

player = Player()
world = World()
done = False
while not done:
    setup_background()
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world.allsprites, True)

    for world in block_hit_list:
        print("WORKING")
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_RIGHT:
                player_x += 5
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to do sprite detection or do you need opinions on if the world should be transparent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sprite collision detection is almost there but incorrect. You seem to know the basics of this concept in this line:

```
block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world.allsprites, True)
```

You are almost there, but here is how you do it. In a `pygame.sprite.spritecollide()` function, you need the sprite's name, the group's name of the other sprite, and either `True` or `False`. In your case, you just need to make a group for your world (assuming you want the things in that order) :

```
world_group = pygame.sprite.Group(world)
```

This line is necessary for your detection code, and will enable that sprite to be removed. If you want to add another world to that group, so you have plenty of worlds, do this and add some code around it if you want to:

```
world_group.add(world)
```

The `add()` function will add a sprite to that group. I recommend you do a loop to make lots of them if necessary. Now to the **collision code!** 
Now we are ready to do this function correctly. I would delete this line first:

```
block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world.allsprites, True)
```

That would be unnecessary and useless for now. You will need to add this `if` statement in the `while` loop but outside your for loop:

```
if pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player, world_group, x):
    #Do something
```

Why did I put `x` instead of `True` or `False`? Because that will be your decision. If you want to delete the sprite in the group after contact, replace `x` with `True`. If you don't want to do that, replace `x` with `False`. These are the basics of collision detection code, and I hope this helps you!